# Configure multiple Kohana applications on one server

Tags: php, apache, wamp, lamp, kohana-3

Currently I am using wamp on a windows machine and have kohana up and running for one site. I would like to deploy another site which is completely separate and uses a different copy of kohana. To do so I added file structure and deployed kohana as follows

```
+wamp
++www
+++site1
++++kohana
+++site2
++++kohana
```

Currently my apache httpd.conf listener is as follows

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

And my hosts file in the windows directory is set up as

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1 site1.localhost
127.0.0.1 site2.localhost
```

Currently when I go to localhost it will go to site1.localhost. Or if i go to site1.localhost it will go to site 1. If I go to site2.localhost the application will redirect to site1.localhost

I am very new to LAMP so this may be a very basic issue, for that I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a virtual host is the answer

```
<VirtualHost site1.localhost>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@site1
    ServerName site1

    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/site1"

    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/site1">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>


    ErrorLog "logs/site1-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/site1-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost site2.localhost>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@site2
    ServerName site2

    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/site2"

    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/site2">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>


    ErrorLog "logs/site2-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/site2-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```